# Replace the return statement below with a statement that returns the first word of theWordList

Tags: java, string, return

Please give me in any tips with my class.
I want to make a return statement that will return the first word 
in my wordList.

```
import java.util.ArrayList ;

    public class WordList {

        private ArrayList<String> theWordList = new ArrayList<String>();

        public void addWord(String s) {
            theWordList.add(s);
        }
        /* Check point 5: complete the method below */

        public String getFirst() {
            /* Replace the return statement bel
             ow with a statement
             * that returns
             * the first word of theWordList (the word at index 0).
             * Hint: use the ArrayList method "get".
             * If there is no first word (theWordList has no words in it),
             * "
             -
             " should be returned.
             */
            return "junk";
        }
```

Comment: Look for the API docs of `List.get(int)` to return a specific index of a list!

Answer (score 3):

You can make it this way

```
   public String getFirst() {
           if(this.theWordList!=null && this.theWordList.size() > 0)
               return this.theWordList.get(0);
           return "-";
        }
```

Note : I have returned `-` (hyphen) when there is no first word in the list or the word list is `null` (which is not going to happen anyway since it is instantiated earlier)

Comment: Don't make the caller check for `null`. The comment in the question above says "-" should be returned if there is no item.

Comment: no problem (and now worthy of the +1). Passing/returning `null` is something that should always be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: @Trengot Hmmm, May i know why returning `null` should be always avoided? I just wanted to understand.

Comment: It forces the client/caller to handle it/add checks where they shouldn't be needed. R C Martin wrote about it better than I could in [clean Code](http://www.e-reading.bz/bookreader.php/134601/Martin_-_Clean_Code_-_A_Handbook_of_Agile_Software_Craftsmanship.pdf) (page 110/111 (141 of pdf))

Comment: @Trengot Thank you very much. It helped me a lot. I read the pages. Very good explanation.

Comment: no problem. The rest of the book is well worth a read as well. Helped me a lot with code style.

Comment: @Trengot Thanks for sharing with me. I will definitely read it soon :) Happy learning!

Answer (score 0):

return theWordList.get(0);

Be sure theWordList is not empty anyway

Answer (score 0):

Make your get function as :

```
 public ArrayList<String> getFirst() {

       return this.theWordList;

    }
```

And write a main () AS :

```
public static void main(String args[]){
            WordList w=new WordList();
            w.addWord("subash");
            //Blah
            //blahhhhh ....

            System.out.println(w.getFirst().get(0));


        }
```

Comment: Why would you return the whole list from a function called `getFirst`?

Comment: My main function will get 0th but function i just wrote it as full list or else u can write it direct as getfirst(){ return this.WordList.get(0);}.Should get him the 0th

Comment: Later he might want to get the last or middle,to compute that he has to return the WordList and then work on it;that was idea behind what i was thinking :)

Comment: In that case write a function called `getWordList`. Have a look at "The principle of least surprise"

Comment: Btw he just asked for tips :) So i gave some :) And principle of least suprise:) i saw it as duplicate is it the same ?